# CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portname) throughing exception

Tags: java, swing, winapi, javax.comm

In the code: CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portname) is not able to indentify the ComPort.

```
{CommPortIdentifier cpi = null;
    try {
        cpi = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portname);
        if (cpi.isCurrentlyOwned()) {

    System.out.println("Error: Port is currently in use");
}
        com = (SerialPort) cpi.open("COM", 10);
        com.setSerialPortParams(9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }}
```

I have tried the solution in the link [how-to-install-java-communications](http://kishor15389.blogspot.de/2011/05/how-to-install-java-communications.html)
but failed, please help me regarding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution provided in the https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/31915 works. In my case, I was using both 32 bit JRE and 64 bit JRE on my PC. I placed the required files according to my java home and used different JRE.

To download comm.jar, win32com.dll and property file I have used http://kishor15389.blogspot.de/2011/05/how-to-install-java-communications.html